# Close a div when other is opened Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not very good at JavaScript/jQuery. I have code that opens a dropdown. I want to add code so that when one dropdown is opened the others close automatically.

Here's the script code:

```
var s;
ShowHideWidget = {

    settings : {
       clickHere : document.getElementById('clickHere'),
       dropdown_login : document.getElementById('dropdown_login')
    },

    init : function() {
        //kick things off
        s = this.settings;
        this.bindUIActions();
    },

    bindUIActions : function() {
        ShowHideWidget.addEvent(s.clickHere, 'click', function() {    
            ShowHideWidget.toggleVisibility(s.dropdown_login);
        });
    },

    addEvent : function(element, evnt, funct) {
        //addEventListener is not supported in <= IE8
        if (element.attachEvent) {
            return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
        } else {
            return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
        }
    },

    toggleVisibility : function(id) {
        $(id).animate({
            left: "",
            height: "toggle"
        }, 500, function() {
        });
    }
};

(function() {
    ShowHideWidget.init();
})();

/*Script 2*/

var k;
ShowHideWidget = {

    settings : {
       clickHere2 : document.getElementById('clickHere2'),
       dropdown_signup : document.getElementById('dropdown_signup')
    },

    init : function() {
        //kick things off
        k = this.settings;
        this.bindUIActions();
    },

    bindUIActions : function() {
        ShowHideWidget.addEvent(k.clickHere2, 'click', function() {    
            ShowHideWidget.toggleVisibility(k.dropdown_signup);
        });
    },

    addEvent : function(element, evnt, funct) {
        //addEventListener is not supported in <= IE8
        if (element.attachEvent) {
            return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
        } else {
            return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
        }
    },

    toggleVisibility : function(id) {
        $(id).animate({
            left: "",
            height: "toggle"
        }, 500, function() {
        });
    }
};

(function() {
    ShowHideWidget.init();
})();
```

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div id="clickHere" class="login_area">Sign up</div>
<div id="clickHere2" class="login_area">Login</div>

<div id="dropdown_login">
    <div class="dropdown_login_header">
        <div class="beeper_login"></div>
    </div>
    Hello World 111
</div>

<div id="dropdown_signup">
    <div class="dropdown_signup_header">
        <div class="beeper_value"></div>
        <div class="beeper_signup"></div>
    </div>
    Hello World 2222
</div>
```

Comment: accept answers to previous questions if those fixed your problem,that will increase the chance of getting more answers for the future questions

Comment: i will kep that in mind :) thanq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to dropdowns div identity them in jquery (say *drop-down*)

```
        <div id="dropdown_login" class="drop-down">
            <div class="dropdown_login_header">
                <div class="beeper_login"></div>
            </div>
            Hello World 111
        </div>

        <div id="dropdown_signup"  class="drop-down">
            <div class="dropdown_signup_header">
                <div class="beeper_value"></div>
                <div class="beeper_signup"></div>
            </div>
            Hello World 2222
        </div>
```

now you can hide the dropdowns anytime by `$('.drop-down').hide()` [this hides all the elements those matches drop-down in class name, so beware this name should not be used anywhere for class.]

in your case this code will come in

```
toggleVisibility : function(id) {

     $('.drop-down').hide();

    $(id).animate({
    left: "",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 500, function() {
```

Comment: This will not work if you want to retain the ability to close an open dropdown when you click. The original code allowed you to close all dropdowns. With this code, one dropdown will always be open.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the drop downs in an extra div like this:

```
<div id="clickHere" class="login_area">Sign up</div>
<div id="clickHere2" class="login_area">Login</div>

<div>
    <div id="dropdown_login">
        <div class="dropdown_login_header">
            <div class="beeper_login"></div>
        </div>
        Hello World 111
    </div>

    <div id="dropdown_signup">
        <div class="dropdown_signup_header">
            <div class="beeper_value"></div>
            <div class="beeper_signup"></div>
        </div>
        Hello World 2222
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you could use the [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method.

```
toggleVisibility : function(id) {
    $(id)
        .siblings().hide()
        .end()
        .animate({
            left: "",
            height: "toggle"
        }, 500, function() {
        });
}
```

Instead of wrapping the drop downs in an extra div, you could add a class to each of the drop down divs. You could then use that class to filter the siblings. For example:

```
$(id).siblings('.drop-down').hide();
```